# "Reading package lists..." freezes until press enter

Tags: apt, package-management, docker

When running `sudo apt-get update` in one of my scripts, it gets hung up on the `Reading package lists...` part. I've let it sit there for an hour and it still doesn't do anything. To clarify, I'm doing this directly after running `apt-cache policy docker-engine` in the process of setting up Docker on Ubuntu.

How this is different from other `reading package list freeze` issues:
When pressing 'enter' (or 'return'), 20 seconds later it continues. There seems to be some errors, but it continues and everything works perfectly. Here is the output when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
ebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 3.13.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-77-generic
done
Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state information... The following extra packages will be installed: crda iw libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 wireless-regdb The following NEW packages will be installed: crda iw libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic wireless-regdb 0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded. Need to get 36.9 MB of archives. After this operation, 152 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Get:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libnl-3-200 amd64 3.2.21-1ubuntu3 [45.7 kB] Get:2 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libnl-genl-3-200 amd64 3.2.21-1ubuntu3 [10.2 kB] Get:3 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main wireless-regdb all 2013.02.13-1ubuntu1 [6,456 B] Get:4 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main crda amd64 1.1.2-1ubuntu2 [15.2 kB] Get:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main iw amd64 3.4-1 [51.7 kB] Get:6 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic amd64 3.13.0-77.121 [36.7 MB] Fetched 36.9 MB in 14s (2,582 kB/s) Selecting previously unselected package libnl-3-200:amd64. (Reading database ... 51153 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ... Unpacking libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) ... Selecting previously unselected package libnl-genl-3-200:amd64. Preparing to unpack .../libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ... Unpacking libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) ... Selecting previously unselected package wireless-regdb. Preparing to unpack .../wireless-regdb_2013.02.13-1ubuntu1_all.deb ... Unpacking wireless-regdb (2013.02.13-1ubuntu1) ... Selecting previously unselected package crda. Preparing to unpack .../crda_1.1.2-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ... Unpacking crda (1.1.2-1ubuntu2) ... Selecting previously unselected package iw. Preparing to unpack .../archives/iw_3.4-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking iw (3.4-1) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic. Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic_3.13.0-77.121_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic (3.13.0-77.121) ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ... Setting up libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) ... Setting up libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) ... Setting up wireless-regdb (2013.02.13-1ubuntu1) ... Setting up crda (1.1.2-1ubuntu2) ... Setting up iw (3.4-1) ... Setting up linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic (3.13.0-77.121) ... Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Ign http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
```

And from there the `apt-get update` works as it normally does. Does anyone know why I have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> to make it not get hung up on `Reading package lists...` ? It's not like they show the error and then I have to press <kbd>enter</kbd>, or that I was prompted with anything.

I'm looking for a way to call `apt-get update` so that I don't have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> (or simulate pressing this if I absolutely have to) if this issue can't be resolved.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this at top of your script

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

which will ameliorate all those "unable to initialize frontend" issues.  When a script is executed unattended (say on remote box or system launched) you are not there to acknowledge interactive prompts so above setting tells the system to just do the default